# Un-bold `group_rows` headings in kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Is there a way to prevent group headers from being rendered as **bold** when using `group_rows` function in `kableExtra`?

I have been using the amazing kableExtra package developed by [@Hao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4586888/hao) to decorate tables outputted from `knitr::kable`. I want to add group headers, but I do not want these to be in bold. These headers are wrapped in `\textbf{}` when outputted to latex, and I have not been able to work out which kableExtra function does this "code decoration".

Reproducible example:

````
---
title: "group_rows kableExtra"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
require(kableExtra)
require(knitr)
```

```{r table, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(head(mtcars), booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex") %>% 
  group_rows("Group 1", 2, 3)
```
````

Comment: Have you tried using `row_spec(row=0)`? Also, let me plug my `huxtable` package, which gives you full control over every cell.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @dash2. Yes, but, row_spec(row=0) changes the column headers and not the grouped headers. The headers also fall outside of the "normal" row count (i.e. the count refers to the original table rows prior to adding the headers). I am very impressed with kableExtra thus far, but will also take a look at your package - thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@bsalzer](https://github.com/bsalzer) on github is helping me recently add some customizable options to `group_rows` including this feature you are asking for. If you install from github, you can do things like

```
knitr::kable(head(mtcars), booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex") %>% 
  group_rows("Group 1", 2, 3, bold = F)
```

and that will do the trick.